# Subtraction "commutative" after the first element?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

What is the name of this property of subtraction: $a - b -c = a - c - b$? I.e. "commutative" for everything but the first element: "when the first element is fixed, the order in which we subtract the other elements from it does not matter".

I'm sorry if this is a really basic question & has been answered elsewhere, but I've just not been able to find anything.

Comment: try it with small #'s and see if the conjecture is true.

Comment: Subtraction (if defined) is rarely associative, so you should arrange brackets.

Comment: First you have to specify what is the "first" element, for example what would be the first element in $a-b+c=a-b-(-c)=c-(-a)-b$, is it $a$ or $c$? You have a function $f(x,y,z)$ for which $f(x,y,z)=f(x,z,y)$. Sometimes it is said that the variables $y$ and $z$ commute, sometimes it is said that $f$ is symmetric in $y$ and $z$.

Comment: I'm sorry if my notation is poor, I don't have a formal mathematical background. What I meant is that if $a$ is the first element, then $a - b - c = a - c - b$, for example $10 - 5 - 2 - 1 = 10 - 5 - 1 - 2 = 10 - 2 - 5 - 1 =  ...$

Answer (score 1):

In the context you've posed it, I'm not sure it has a name.

I think the proper context for this question is that of functions.  In this context, we define $f_y(x) = x-y$ and your property just becomes $$f_b\circ f_c = f_c \circ f_b$$ That is, it is a commutative property of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

If a binary operation is associative and satisfies $zxy=zyx$, then the semigroup is called *[left normal](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195522133)*. See "left normal bands", for example. For non-associative magmas, nobody considered this. So you can call this "left normality". The right normality is defined as $xyz=yxz$ and normality is $zxyt=zyxt$ (everything for associative operations).